# Sending SIGINT to process launched from Python does not yield same result as when process is launched from shell

Tags: python, linux, signals, sh

I am writing a script that is supposed to launch an interactive shell of a third-party program from within python in linux (the third party program  is Stata). The purpose of the script is to control the stdin and stdout of the interactive shell so I can access it from an editor and other scripts.

When started from within a linux shell, Stata launches an interactive shell where you can run Stata commands. When I press control+C or use some other way to send a SIGINT signal to Stata, it will stop executing the current command and will return to the interactive shell, but it will not kill the Stata process. I want to replicate this behavior for Stata launched from python.

When I send a SIGINT signal to a Stata process launched from python, it will kill the process instead of just stopping execution of the current command.

The behavior in the shell is:

```
> /usr/local/stata14/stata
(...other stuff...)
. forval i = 1/100000 {
  2. sleep 10
  3. di "`i'"
  4. }
1
2
3
4
(I hit CTRL+C)
--Break--
r(1);
.
```

The following python program launches Stata from within python:

```
def handler(signum, frame):
   stata.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)

stata = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/local/stata14/stata"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, preexec_fn=os.setpgrp)

(... other stuff hat handles forwarding stata.stdout to sys.stdout in a separate thread...)

while true:
   time.sleep(0.1)
   userinput = raw_input(". ")
   print(userinput, file=stata.stdin)
   stata.stdin.flush()
   print(stata.poll())
```

with the same for loop running in the subprocess, produces:

```
> /usr/local/stata14/stata
. forval i = 1/100000 {
  2. sleep 10
  3. di "`i'"
  4. }
1
2
3
4
-2
-2
-2
```

and any further attempt to write to stata.stdin then produces

```
print(userinput, file=stata.stdin)
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Anyone understands why this is happening? I already tried using subprocess.Popen with shell = True. In this case, Popen launches an sh process and a Stata process. If I send SIGINT to the sh process, nothing happens. If I send it to Stata, the same problem as with shell=False arises.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use `kill -int` instead to simulate what your doing from Python,  you'll see the same behavior. Ctrl+C will send sigint to the entire foreground process group.

Comment: I put the subprocess in a different group using preexec_fn=os.setpgrp (hard to spot because the code above does not wrap lines). But it's true that I do observe the same behavior when I use kill -int on the process launched from python. Anyways: how can I replicate the behavior of the process launched without python for the process launched in python?

Comment: Apparently the underlying program just acts differently when it is run in a terminal. So I solved this using pty.fork() instead of subprocess.